# Unable to remotely connect to docker container

Tags: linux, docker

I am new to docker, this is my first attempt at using it.

I have setup a docker container on a AWS DEBIAN 9 host and started it:

```
#docker-compose up -d
```

This is the section related to the web app:

```
  waweb:
    image: docker.whatsapp.biz/web:v${WA_API_VERSION:?Run docker-compose with env var WA_API_VERSION (ex. WA_API_VERSION=2.29.2 docker-compose <command> <options>)}
    command: ["/opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_mysql.sh", "/opt/whatsapp/bin/launch_within_docker.sh"]
    ports:
     - "9090:443"
    volumes:
     - whatsappMedia:/usr/local/wamedia
    env_file:
      - db.env
    environment:
      WACORE_HOSTNAME: wacore
      # This is the version of the docker templates being used to run WhatsApp Business API
      WA_RUNNING_ENV_VERSION: v2.2.3
      ORCHESTRATION: DOCKER-COMPOSE
    depends_on:
      - "db"
      - "wacore"
    links:
      - db
      - wacore
    network_mode: bridge
```

When I test this it shows that all appears to be correct and it is listening on 9090:

```
# docker-compose ps
     Name                   Command               State                   Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
wabiz_db_1       docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      0.0.0.0:33060->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
wabiz_wacore_1   /opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_ ...   Up      6250/tcp, 6251/tcp, 6252/tcp, 6253/tcp
wabiz_waweb_1    /opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_ ...   Up      0.0.0.0:9090->443/tcp
```

and:

```
# netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      18818/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      18818/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      32144/docker-proxy
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      32361/docker-proxy
```

I can test-connect to this locally:

```
# telnet localhost 9090
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Yet when I attempt connect to it remotely, the connection is refused.

The firewall ports are all open to my IP (1-65535), I can remotely telnet to port 22 and also create a python simple-http-server and connect to that remotely too.

I thought that maybe IPV6 was being forced, but it is not:

```
# sysctl net.ipv6.bindv6only
net.ipv6.bindv6only = 0
```

Any suggestions on what the issue may be ?

Comment: Can you check if there is firewall enabled on the machine? If not then try restarting the docker container.

Comment: Thanks, but see my original post: "The firewall ports are all open to my IP (1-65535), I can remotely telnet to port 22 and also create a python simple-http-server and connect to that remotely too."